# XQuery - Why there is difference in result?

Tags: xquery, basex

```
<Docs>
 <Doc>
   <Title>Electromagnetic Fields</Title>
    <Info>
      <Vol name="Physics"/>
      <Year>2006</Year>
    </Info>
    <SD>
      <Info>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<P>blh blah blah.</P></Para>
      </Info>
    </SD>
    <LD>
      <Info>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<P>blah blah blah.</P></Para>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<P>blah blah blah.</P></Para>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<P>emf waves blah.</P></Para>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<B>emf waves</B> blah.</Para>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<P>emf waves blah.</P></Para>
        <Para>blah waves blah.<B>emf</B> waves blah.</Para>
        <Para>emf blah blah.<I>waves blah.</I></Para>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<B>emf waves</B> blah.</Para>
        <Para>blah blah blah.<P><I>emf</I> waves blah.</P></Para>
      </Info>
    </LD>
</Doc>      
</Docs>
```

Query 1 -

```
for $x in ft:search("Article", ("emf","waves"), map{'mode':='all words'})/ancestor::*:Doc
  return $x/Title
```

I am getting 62 Hits

Query 2 -

```
for $x in ft:search("Article", ("emf","waves"), map{'mode':='all words'})
  return $x/ancestor::*:Doc/Title
```

I am getting 159 Hits

Query 3 -

```
for $x in doc("Article")/Doc[Info[Vol/@name="Physics" and Year ge "2006" and Year le "2010"]]
[SD/Info/Para/text() contains text {"emf","waves"} all words or
SD/Info/Para/P/text() contains text {"emf","waves"} all words or
LD/Info/Para/text() contains text {"emf","waves"} all words or
SD/Info/Para/P/text() contains text {"emf","waves"} all words or
SD/Info/Para/P/B/text() contains text {"emf","waves"} all words or
SD/Info/Para/P/I/text() contains text {"emf","waves"} all words or
SD/Info/Para/P/U/text() contains text {"emf","waves"} all words]
    return $x/Title
```

This results in 224 hits. In the 3rd one, I am using all the nodes which are actually present. `I`, `B` and `U` are for Italic, Bold and Underline the text.

Why this difference ?

Comment: You need to give us some example document, otherwise that question cannot be answered.

Comment: @JensErat -  Ok. I will edit the post and add some example document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries 1 and 2 pretty much look the same, however the path expression in Q1 results in `Doc` elements. So if there are multiple matching nodes below a single `Doc`, that `Doc` will count just once in Q1, whereas each node is counted individually in Q2. This is due to the fact that the node sequence resulting from a path expression, by definition, is duplicate-free.

Q3 is different, but while Q1 and Q2 depend on the properties of a full-text index, Q3 doesn't. If e.g. the index is case-sensitive, you'll get less results from it than from a `contains text` predicate.

So from the quoted counts, I'd assume that the text index comes up with 159 matching nodes in 62 documents, while being specified as more restrictive than a plain `contains text`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query searches for `Doc` elements which have a certain property, and returns one result for each such `Doc` element.

Your second query searches for nodes of any kind which have a (related) property, and returns one result for each such node.

Your third query searches for text nodes which have another (related) property.

Whenever there are `Doc` elements containing more than one node matching the full-text search criterion, the first and second queries will return different numbers of hits.  And similarly for the third query, vis-a-vis the others.